# What would be the phrase or proverb or idiom for "A robber is recognized or appreciated by a thief"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, proverb-requests

What would be the phrase or proverb or idiom for "A robber is recognized or appreciated by a thief"?

For instance, a jailbird criminal is supported/helped/appreciated/awarded by a corrupt politician or vice versa etc.

Answer (score 3):

***Birds of a feather flock together***

> *Prov.* Similar people tend to associate with each other. *I always thought Amy was pretentious, and now she's going out with that snobbish boy, Louis. Birds of a feather flock together.* George: *Why do you think Donald is dishonest?* Ned: *All his friends are dishonest.* *Birds of a feather flock together.*
>
> [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Birds+of+a+feather+flock+together)

Answer (score 0):

**Honour amongst thieves** or **thick as thieves** could work or perhaps **conspiracy**